# How can I insert conditional logic into a render array?

Tags: theming

Given the following render array, I'd like to insert some logic so that that $number of rows are created, but I can't just insert a `for` loop in the middle of defining my render array, I don't think. What can I do? $number will always vary.

```
function foo($bar, $number) {
  return $table = array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => array(t('Header 1'), t('Header 2')
    '#rows' => array(
   // for ($count = 1; $count <= $number; ++$count) {
        array($bar[$count], $bar[$count])
   // }
    )
  );
}
```

Thanks

Comment: See here for more info: http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_table/7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create the $rows array with PHP before passing it to theme_table:

```
function foo($bar, $number) {
  $rows = array();
  for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i++) {
    $rows[] = $bar[$i];
  }
  return array(
    '#theme' => 'table',
    '#header' => array(t('Header 1'), t('Header 2')),
    '#rows' => $rows,
  );
}
```